# website screenshot on my server depending on USER

Tags: php, screenshot, wkhtmltopdf

I came upon many similar questions like this but I could not find simple answer. My goal is to create my web page thumbnail onto my server for a particular User (depending on `SESSION`). Website is dynamic means for every different user content changes like that contents of users on facebook.

What I need to do here is generate a screenshot when user experiences a problem with the application and click the capture button

[image]

I got many options like

- **libwkhtmltox**
- **wkhtmltopdf**

but not getting which I should use also suggest other if better.

I have **linux server** and using **core PHP** and have shell access to it.

**Please don't refer external site** as they are unable to get snapshot in my case (as I said `SESSION` variable is maintained for every user).

Please help me with the tutorial.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Just to make that clear... you want to get a screenshot of what the user sees if an error occurs?

Comment: Yes also user can put suggestion on some page with screenshot

Comment: I think you'll find that very hard to accomplish. Logging the server state to text files is the usual way to do this.

Comment: Please help me with the solution I spent lot of time finding the answer SO is my last try...Please

Comment: Pleading doesn't make this any more possible. Off the top of my head I'd say this is impossible without getting the user to install some browser plugin, which is a nonsense solution.

Comment: At least give me some tutorial...   Or some other option for doing it

Comment: As I said, **log your server state to text files**. Automatically snapping a screenshot of the user's browser is **virtually impossible**. And I don't know what you hope to gain from that anyway. You'd get a screenshot of an error page, so? If there are errors visible to the user, you can get those in your code and log them, you don't need to take the long way around via screenshots. Open a new question if you need more help with proper error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libwkhtmltox` and `wkhtmltopdf` are both great technologies for capturing images of web pages.  However, the problem is that it's really hard to get these technologies to have the same session as your user, if not impossible.  Additionally, many errors users experience aren't reproducible on a second request.  (Errors caused by db connection errors, caching, etc.)  So doing something like this will have limited value.  One alternative would be to throw a popup when they click your `send errorpage snap` that explains how to take a screenshot.

If you absolutely want to go down this path of automating the screenshot, here's a crazy, probably stupidly insecure idea.  As `wkhtmltopdf` is built on webkit, there are options to set cookies.  As long as your php `session` is cookie based, you could pass the user's `session_id` to `wkhtmltopdf`, and hijack your own user's session, thereby recreating the page when `wkhtmltopdf` makes the request.  I'm so getting downvoted for suggesting this...

Comment: +1 for answering.Let me try this also will u please paste link or steps which I must follow.Thanks for the answer